# How to use entity field in Hibernate @Formula

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Many times I'm using @Formula in my entities. But always it was a simple query or stored procedure with parameter which I can take as filed from table. Now I need to user some property from related object. But I see exception when try to get object from DB. Please see an example below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MINISTRY")
public class Ministry {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    // unnecessary code

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DEP_NAME")
    private String departmentName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MINISTRY_ID")
    private Ministry ministry;

    // unnecessary code
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Department department;

    @Formula("test_package.calc_something(department.ministry.id)")
    private BigDecimal someMetric;

    // unnecessary code

}
```

How I should use entity prop in @Formula. 
 I don't want to write something like

```
select d.ministry.id from Department d ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the JavaDoc of `Formula` you will see:

> The formula has to be a valid SQL fragment

So you will have to use SQL like:

```
 @Formula("test_package.calc_something("
            + "select DEP.MINISTRY_ID from DEPARTMENT DEP where DEP.ID = DEPARTMENT_ID"
         + ")")
 private BigDecimal someMetric;
```

The only thing that is modified by Hibernate in the fragment before writing it to SQL: It will add the table alias to your columns (as you can't predict that). I mention that, as only a rudimentary SQL parser is used for that, which will insert the alias at wrong positions for more complex fragments.

*A remark about performance:* The formula is executed for every `Department` entity that you load, even if you only want to use the attribute for sorting or filtering (just guessing from the name of the attribute) - unless you use  `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and turn *bytecode instrumentation* on (or emulate that with `FieldHandled`).

Comment: Thanks for your answering. But I was wrote bad example. Task is to take the parameters of the related objects. I updated example. Thanks in advance.